# making predictions using classification models with multiple independent variables in hand

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification

I am trying to make a simple classification using Logistic Regression. I fit the model and scale the values using a standard scaler. how can I make a single prediction after that? I am getting the same result for different values. For every value, I am getting 0. the prediction I am getting from single inputs does not resemble with the result from the prediction made by the testing dataset. Can someone please give me a hand?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("Social_Network_Ads.csv")
x = dataset.iloc[:, 2:4].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values
print(dataset)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)

x_values = [36, 36000]
x_values = np.array(x_values).reshape(1, -1)
x_values = scaler.transform(x_values)
pred = classifier.predict(x_values)
print("single prediction: ", pred)
```

Comment: Are you applying the same scaling on your test example?

Comment: I am scaling both the training and testing data set. also for the individual inputs I applied the scaling.

Comment: Is your data imbalanced?

Comment: no, it's not, actually, the prediction works well with the testing dataset. the only problem is when I use single inputs.